# AGOL buildingexplorer. Can't show all the layers of my 3D Models at once, only 1 model at the same time

Tags: arcgis-online, 3d, revit

I have 2 3D models in my scene. I want to show all the layers of these models but for some reason I can only see all the layers of 1 model at the same time. I think it has to do with the **building explorer tool**. When I click on the tool and then on a model. It shows all the layers of this model but doesn't show all the layers of the other model.

[image]
Above: How it is normally shown

Below: When I select this building, all the layers show. But the other model has just 1 layer visible instead all of them
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the current supported experience with Build Scene Layers and the Building Explorer tool. The building explorer is currently used for only one building at a time.

Comment: Even when I don't use the Building Explorer Tool I still can't see all the layers

Comment: Can you share the BIM dataset you are using and we can investigate it further. You can zip it and upload the data to AGOL and invite russell_jsapi to the group and I can see try to repro the issue.